# Units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a + bi)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I want to find the size of the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a + bi)$. I am not really sure how to do this. I know in the special case that $a+bi$ is prime, the answer is $N(a+ib) - 1$ because $|\mathbb{Z}[i]/(a + bi)| = N(a+bi)$ ($N$ represents the norm). However, I don't know how to do this for nonprime Gaussian integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can write $a+bi$ as a unit times a product of irreducibles:
$$a+bi=i^k\pi_1^{c_1}\cdots\pi_n^{c_n}$$
where $k$ is an integer, the $c_j$ are positive integers,
and $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_n$ are non-associated irreducibles.
Then
$$\Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)\cong\prod_{j=1}^n\Bbb Z[i]/(\pi_j^{c_j}).$$
The unit group of the ring $\Bbb Z[i]/(\pi_j^{c_j})$ has $(N\pi_j-1)(N\pi_j)^{c_j-1}$
elements, and so $\Bbb Z[i]/(a+bi)$ has
$$\prod_{j=1}^n(N\pi_j-1)(N\pi_j)^{c_j-1}$$
units.

Comment: Is the first isomorphism the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @Mike  Exactly!${}$

Comment: Could you explain why the unit group $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(\pi_j^{c_j})$ has size $(N\pi_j - 1)(N\pi_j)^{c_j - 1}$?

Comment: It's  basically the same argument that $\Bbb Z/(p^m)$ has $(p-1)p^{m-1}$ units. @Mike

Comment: I am familiar with the argument that $\mathbb{Z}/(p^m) $has $(p-1)p^{m-1}$ elements, but it requires me to know what the elements are in $\mathbb{Z}/{p^{m}}$ (namely the residue classes of $1,2,3,\ldots,p^{m-1}$. I don't know what $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(\pi_j^{c_j})$ looks like.

Comment: @Mike It's an Artinian local ring; the units are those elements which are nonzero modulo $\pi_j$.